# sending the list of posts without description in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a blog with django rest framework for the backend .  I have a Posts model that has a 'description' TextField. I want to use this model for both 'showing a list of all posts' and 'showing a single post'.I don't want the description fields to be sent for the blog page and send it just for the single posts pages. this is my code :

Post Model:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    description = models.TextField(default = "")
```

Post ViewSet:

```
class PostsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

serializer_class = serializers.PostsSerializer
queryset = models.Posts.objects.all()
```

Post Serializer:

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.Posts
    fields = '__all__'
```

Note: when I go to http://example.com/Posts , I like to see all posts without the Description. but for http://example.com/Posts/1, I want the description as well as other Fields.

Comment: You can create an extra serializer that inherits from the old, but excludes the description field.

Comment: thank you . I used your solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by several methods
**Method-1 :** Overriding the **`__init__()`** method of serializer

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Posts
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'view' in self.context and self.context['view'].action == 'list':
            self.fields.pop('description')
```

You are using `viewset` class for the views. So, we could get [specific actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) from **`.action`** attribute

**Method-2 :** Use different serializer (as @Willem Van Onsem mentioned ) and adjust your **`get_serializer_class()`** for that

```
# serializers.py
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Posts
        fields = '__all__'


class PostListSerializer(PostDetailSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Posts
        exclude = ('description',)


# views.py
class PostsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.PostsSerializer
    queryset = models.Posts.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return PostListSerializer
        return PostDetailSerializer
```

Comment: thank you for your answer . I used the method-2 . what I comments was a simplified version of my app and there's more fields to exclude . So i thought it's better to use different serializers like you said.thank you very much

Comment: That's the DRF way :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to introduce *two* serializers, one for the list, and one for the detail page.

So then it can look like:

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Posts
        fields = '__all__'
```

then we can write the list serializer as:

```
class PostListSerializer(PostDetailSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Posts
        exclude = ('description', )
```

So now if you make custom changes to the `PostDetailSerializer` (for example how the name is rendered), then this will also have impact on how the list is serialized. We can also just make two serializers without this inheritance, if we want to make these "independent" of each other.

Then we thus can make two views:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer

class RetrievePostView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
```

Comment: It's better if we use `ModelViewSet` class rather than `ListCreateAPIView` and `RetrieveAPIView`

Comment: thank you . I used your solution . what I comments was a simplified version of my app . So i think it's better to use different serializers like you said .